# Get the "filename" in a specific string

Tags: jquery, string

```
url("http://localhost/garg/public/img/slides/9234385e2911fd07346cae2d78548d20.jpg")
```

I would like to get the **9234385e2911fd07346cae2d78548d20.jpg** part.

I've tried to slice my way through, but it doesn't really work.

```
string.slice(0,-2);
string.slice(0,5);
....
```

But it's not very efficient. How can I do it elsewhy?

Comment: Here's an idea: search for the last occurrence of `/` and grab anything that follows. Although of course this won't work for any random URL. You can search with [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).

Comment: string.split("/").pop();

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using this approach using REGEX:

```
var fullPath = "http://localhost/garg/public/img/slides/9234385e2911fd07346cae2d78548d20.jpg";
var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

alert (filename);
```

This is however a simpler approach

```
 var fullPath = "http://localhost/garg/public/img/slides/9234385e2911fd07346cae2d78548d20.jpg";
 var filename = fullPath​​​​​​​.split('/').pop();
 alert (filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[lastIndexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp)** : find last occurrence of the passed parameter.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://9234385e2911fd07346cae2d78548d20.jpg)**

```
str.substr(str.lastIndexOf ("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use it this way :

```
$("input[name='attachment']").change(function() {
      console.log('fileName');
    var fileName = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
    console.log(fileName);
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nSf7w/157/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var match = "http://localhost/garg/public/img/slides/9234385e2911fd07346cae2d78548d20.jpg".match(/[^/]*$/);
var filename = match ? match[0] : '';
```